# Producing PDF report using user input files - Shiny

Tags: r, pdf, latex, shiny, knitr

I have created R code that allows me to transform and analyze data and then output the results in form of tables into PDF report. Recently, I decided to share my work with colleges, who are not familiar with R. Therefore, I want to create Shiny app that will allow them to use my work without having R installed. The Shiny app will serve as platform to upload data and then download the report. Unfortunately, I am not able to output my results into PDF.

My Shiny code looks the following way:

```
library(knitr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           wellPanel(
             fileInput(inputId = "files",
                       label = "Choose csv files",
                       accept=c('text/csv', 
                                'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                                '.csv'),
                       multiple = TRUE),
             textInput('filename', 'File name', value = ''),
             downloadButton('report', label = 'Download PDF')
             )
           )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  data_set <- reactive({if(!is.null(input$files)) {
    max_table = length(input$files[,1])

    lst <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(input$files[,1])){
      lst[[i]] <- read.csv(input$files[[i, 'datapath']], sep = ",", header = TRUE, skip = 4, dec = ".")
    }

    lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) xtable(x))}})



  output$report = downloadHandler(
    filename = reactive({paste0(input$filename,'.pdf')}),

    content = function(file) {
      out = knit2pdf('pdf_shell.Rnw', clean = TRUE)
      file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
    },

    contentType = 'application/pdf'
  )
  }


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And my `.Rnw` file looks as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}
\textbf{Test Name:}& \Sexpr{input$filename} \\
\textbf{Date:}&  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

<<echo = FALSE , message = F, >>=
data_set
@


\end{document}
```

Obviously loading the `data_set` is not working and I have no idea how to move forward. 
For now I would like to just output the table created out of the data that I load into the Shiny.

I would really appreciate your help.

**Side note:** the csv files are externally simple data frames consisting of headers and columns filled with data.

When coutputed in R they should look something like that:

```
$data001
 A   B   C   D   E
 X   10  30  50  70
 Y   20  40  60  80
```

Comment: May be it because in shiny data_set -- reactive , so try to use data_set_1 in .Rnw and `content = function(file) { data_set_1=data_set()
      out = knit2pdf('pdf_shell.Rnw', clean = TRUE)
      file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
    }`

Comment: @Batanichek thank you very much for you response it worked and I am able to output values into PDF. I have to improve my understanding of shiny,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem because in `shiny`

`data_set` is `reactive` so you cant use it like

```
<<echo = FALSE , message = F, >>=
data_set
@
```

in your `.Rnw`

So try

## .Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabularx}
\textbf{Test Name:}& \Sexpr{input$filename} \\
\textbf{Date:}&  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

<<echo = FALSE , message = F, >>=
data_set_1
@


\end{document}
```

## handler

```
downloadHandler(
    filename = reactive({paste0(input$filename,'.pdf')}),

    content = function(file) {
      data_set_1=data_set()
      out = knit2pdf('pdf_shell.Rnw', clean = TRUE)
      file.rename(out, file) # move pdf to file for downloading
    },

    contentType = 'application/pdf'
  )
```

Or may be simple `data_set()` in `.Rnw`

Comment: Both `data_set_1=data_set()` in handler and `data_set()` in `.Rnw` work. I really appreciate your help.